# QTableWidget has a column with checkable items but I can't commit to MYSQL db the toggling of the checkboxes

Tags: mysql, qt, sql-update, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

The "Locked" column in the database has items with int values "0" or "2".
In the QTableWidget, all the "Locked" items are displayed as checkboxes with their correct values: 
...

```
lockedItem = new QTableWidgetItem(col2);
//...

// Loop ...

if (lockedItem->text() == "0") {
    lockedItem->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
} else if (lockedItem->text() == "2") {
    lockedItem->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
}

ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,2,lockedItem);

//...

ui->tableWidget->show();

tableModel = ui->tableWidget->model();

connect(tableModel, SIGNAL(dataChanged ( const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex & )),
    this, SLOT(lockedItemChanged( QModelIndex )));
```

---

And whenever I toggle a checkbox, the following slot gets called:

```
void MainWindow::lockedItemChanged(QModelIndex itemIndex)
{
    int row = itemIndex.row();
    int col = itemIndex.column();
    QVariant value = ui->tableWidget->item(row, col)->checkState();

    ui->tableWidget->item(row,col)->setData(Qt::EditRole, value);

    qDebug() << "item changed at: (" << row << "," << col <<")"<< value;
}
```

---

In the QtableWidget everything looks good and I see next to each checkbox the correct value displayed. For example if I check a box in the "Locked" column, "2" is displayed next to it and if I uncheck then "0" is displayed. But how to commit these (check/uncheck or the "0" and "2") changes back to MYSQL db?
What am I missing? I thought the setData should do it.

Comment: I've noticed online that QTableView is used way more than QtableWidget. And since working with QTableWidget, I feel there's lot of limitations and many functions from QSQlTableModel I can't use because they are private.

Comment: Still need an answer please. Can QTableWidget update the database or no? If yes then why am I not successful at doing it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information missing in your question. But to answer your question in the comments:

`QTableWidget`, same as `QTreeWidget` and `QListWidget`, bring their own model with them. That internal model isn't supposed to be changed from the outside, rather you would use the public functions and signals `QTableWidget` provides.

For simple database interaction it should be enough to connect to the `dataChanged()` signal as you did. But when you call

```
ui->tableWidget->item(row,col)->setData(Qt::EditRole, value);
```

you basically overwrite the data in the model with the same data you just retrieved.
Instead, you should apply the change to the database, like this:

```
myDatabase->updateLockedState(row, col, value);
```

If you want direct mapping between database and GUI table, you should subclass `QSqlTableModel` (or create your own `QAbstractItemModel`-derived model which has a `QSqlDatabase` as member) and set that as the model of a `QTableView`.